# Apple Mach-0 linker error when adding Parse to existing FB SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, google-plus

My first question here, so pardon my mistakes. 
I've created an app and managed to integrate both google plus login(sdk 1.7.1) and fb login(sdk 4.2.0). Everything worked fine till here. Later, to let people manually sign up, I've added parse(sdk version 1.7.4).

Now when the -ObjC linker flag is not present in the build settings, it builds fine and I'm able to sign up and do things with parse. But both FB and G+ throw errors like: "Unknown class FBSDKLoginButton in Interface Builder file, Unknown class GPPSignInButton in Interface Builder file, Unknown class FBSDKProfilePictureView in Interface Builder file", etc. However, I can login in to facebook using a custom button. Google simply doesn't respond. Both buttons are views which have custom classes.

If I remove the -ObjC linker flag, the I get 42 errors as below:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ReadTaskString(unsigned int, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::WriteModuleStream(unsigned int, MDRawModule*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImage::DynamicImage(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, std::string, unsigned long, unsigned int, int) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::InstallHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef* std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*>(unsigned long, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned short*, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > >, unsigned long, unsigned short const&) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MDMemoryDescriptor*, std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> > >, MDMemoryDescriptor const&) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned short*, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > >, unsigned long, unsigned short const&) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(ios_exception_minidump_generator.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_file_writer.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(file_id.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in ParseCrashReporting(macho_id.o)
      ...
  "typeinfo for std::bad_alloc", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table22 in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for google_breakpadPFC_::IosExceptionMinidumpGeneratorPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(ios_exception_minidump_generator.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for std::bad_alloc", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::InstallHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      ___32-[BreakpadControllerPFC_ start:]_block_invoke in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _BreakpadCreatePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UninstallHandler(bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::InstallHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::MinidumpGenerator(unsigned int, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      ...
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      ___32-[BreakpadControllerPFC_ start:]_block_invoke in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _BreakpadCreatePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::InstallHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::MinidumpGenerator(unsigned int, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char*>(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::allocator<unsigned char> const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      _BreakpadReleasePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadAddUploadParameterPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadCreatePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadSetKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadRemoveUploadParameterPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadRemoveKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      _BreakpadReleasePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadAddUploadParameterPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadCreatePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadSetKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadRemoveUploadParameterPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadRemoveKeyValuePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_get_exception_ptr", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::InstallHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  "___cxa_guard_abort", referenced from:
      +[BreakpadControllerPFC_ sharedInstance] in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
  "___cxa_guard_acquire", referenced from:
      +[BreakpadControllerPFC_ sharedInstance] in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
  "___cxa_guard_release", referenced from:
      +[BreakpadControllerPFC_ sharedInstance] in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      +[BreakpadControllerPFC_ sharedInstance] in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
      ___32-[BreakpadControllerPFC_ start:]_block_invoke in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in ParseCrashReporting(BreakpadController.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadReleasePFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      _BreakpadAddUploadParameterPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I've tried: 
1. searched extensively on the subject
2. deleted bolts.framework from both parse and facebook, cleaned, added and built again. 
3. added searchpaths for FBSDK, Google sdk and Parse to Framework searchpaths.
4. rechecked all app Ids
5. added all the necessary frameworks as mentioned in their respective documentation.

Using xcode with objC 6.3.2 and iphone 6 as my simulator.

I know I have to integrate google maps soon and I've been reading that maps will not work without the -ObjC linker flag. (I might be wrong). 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the Facebook related errors, you seem to use the version of the ParseFacebookUtils that do not support v4.x of the Facebook SDK. If you switch to using ParseFacebookUtilsV4 these errors should go away